# Uploading a custom display template will not have its related .js file created and the custom template is not showing inside the DisplayTemple list

Tags: development, display-template, content-search-web-part

I want to create a custom display template to be used inside my Content Search WebPart. so i follow the steps inside this [link](http://www.sharemuch.com/2014/07/23/how-to-customize-the-look-of-the-sharepoint-content-search-web-part-results/).

where i mainly went to :-

- site settings >> Web Designer Galleries >> Master Page Gallery >> Display Templete folder >> Content Web Parts folder.
- i download the `Control_List.html` file. then rename the copy to `Control_ListMY.html`.
- do some modifications to the `Control_ListMy.html`.
- upload the  `Control_ListMy.html`.
- publish the `Control_ListMy.html` as a major version.

but i am facing these problems:-

- Inside the Content Web Part folders the related .js was not created automatically.
- when i add a new Content Search web part the new display template is not showing under the Display Template list :-

[image]

so can anyone adivce on these problems please?

Answer (score 1):

Check your webtype. For the conversion to be done the **publishing infrastructure** is needed.

If you need your DisplayTempaltes in a TeamSite or another page without publishing infrastructure, simply upload your Templates to a PublishingSite and download the created `.js` files.

You could also activate the publishing features, but this will result in a lot of side effects.

Comment: Yes my current team site does not have publishing infrastructure enabled. I remember in the past i tried enabling this service inside my test team site collection and i got a lot of side effect.So seems even inside my team site collection which have its  publishing infrastructure disabled i can not upload custom display templates. so my problem is not really that the .js file was not created automatically but that the custom display template will not appear under "Display Template" list inside my Content Search WebPart if the publishing infrastructure service is disabled! is this correct?

Comment: actually no - I am perfectly able to select my uploaded `.js` displaytemplates in teamsites. Have you checked the `TargetControlType`? Maybe its not set to your desired webpart.

Comment: yes the problem that in my case the custom display templete will not show inside the content Search web part. now i tried the same steps inside a team site which have publishing infrastructure enabled and it worked well.. so not sure if adding a custom display template will work inside a team site that have the publishing infrastructure serivce disabled

Comment: as I said - I dont have to enable any features to make my displayTemplates work.